# Rounding Up Minutes above 8, 23, 38, 53 to the nearest quarter hour

Tags: excel

Here’s a challenge for someone.  I’m trying to round session times up to the nearest quarter hour (I report my total client hours for license credentialing)

```
8 minutes or above: round up to 15     
23 minutes or above: round up to 30        
38 minutes or above: round up to 45      
53 minutes or above: round up to 60
```

Ex: in the first quarter hour, minutes below 8 will be their exact value: 1=1, 2=2, 3=3.

When 8 is entered, it is automatically rounded up to 15 (the same holds true for the rest of the hour: ex:  16=16, 17=17, 18=18, 19=19, 20=20, 21=21, 22=22.  But 23 through 29 are all rounded up to 30.

Ideally, I could enter both hours and minutes in a single column, ex: 1.54

However, I realize that it may be necessary to create a separate column for hours and minutes in order to make this work (i.e., so that my formula is only concerned with rounding up minutes.  I can add my hours and minutes together after the minutes are rounded.)  Thus:

```
Column A = Hours (3 hours maximum)   
Column B = Minutes  
Column C = Minutes Rounded up to nearest ¼ hour     
Column D = Col A + Col C
```

In column B I would like to enter minutes as 1 through 60 (no decimal- i.e., in General, not Time format)

38 minutes in column B would automatically be rounded up to 45 minutes in column C

Does anyone have any ideas?  How can I do this using the fewest number of columns?

[A Previously posted question - "Round up to nearest quarter" - introduces the concept of Math.Ceiling.  Is this something I should use?  I couldn't wrap my head around the answer).

With Grateful Thanks,

~ Jay

Comment: Why store the roundups at all?  Deal with it when you display/use it.

Comment: That `ColumnA - ColumnD` table structure worries me.  I would go with `SessionStart` and `SessionEnd` columns (both DATETIME, assuming SQL Server is used).  Then have your application business layer "do the math" for the rounding issue.

Comment: Hi Jay.  You've posted this in the SQL Server part of this forum, and I've answered it as if the question was about SQL Server, not Excel.  None of your tags indicate this is an Excel issue, nor the opening question.  I'd suggest that you update the question and tags so that others don't come to this conclusion.  So far two of us have thought this was a SQL Server issue.

Comment: why would you want to do this? are you sure you want to do this? why not just store straight values?

Answer (score 0):

Assume "sessions" is your table (CTE below contains 2 sample records), with session start time & end time stored (as noted in comments above, just store these data points, don't store the calculated values).  You might be able to do the rounding as below.  (not sure if this is what you want, since it either rounds up *or* down...  do you not want to round down?)

```
;WITH   sessions AS (
    SELECT  CAST('20140317 12:00' AS DATETIME) AS session_start, CAST('20140317 12:38' AS DATETIME) AS session_end
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CAST('20140317 12:00' AS DATETIME), CAST('20140317 12:37:59' AS DATETIME) AS session_end
)
SELECT  *, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, session_start, session_end) AS session_time
        , ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, session_start, session_end)/15.0, 0) * 15.0 AS bill_time
FROM    sessions;
```

EDIT:

Hi Jay, I don't think you mentioned it is an Excel problem!  I was assuming SQL.  As Stuart suggested in a comment above, it would be helpful if you modified your question to indicate it is for Excel, so that others can possibly get help from this dialog in the future.

With Excel, you can do it with two columns that contain the session start date and time (column A) and session end date and time (column B), plus two formulas:

```
Column C (Actual Minutes) = ROUND((B1-A1) * 1440,0)
Column D (Billing Minutes) = (FLOOR(C1/15, 1) * 15) + IF(MOD(C1,15) >= 8, 15, MOD(C1,15))
```

This is what my table looks like:

```
3/18/2014 12:00 3/18/2014 12:38 38  45
3/18/2014 14:00 3/18/2014 14:37 37  37
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so promptly.  I’m no Excel whiz, I just know how to find answers to questions online.   

First, I want to round up, not down.

Here’s what a reference table might look like:

Minutes:      Rounded Up To:
1 1
2 2 
3 3
4 4
5 5 
6 6
7 7
8 15
9 15
10 15 
11 15
12 15
13 15
14 15
15 15
16 16
17 17
18 18
ETC.

Again, I’d like minutes to be rounded up as follows (the 4 thresholds are 8, 23, 38 & 53)

8 minutes or above: round up to 15 
23 minutes or above: round up to 30 
38 minutes or above: round up to 45 
53 minutes or above: round up to 60

~ Jay

Comment: Thank you for responding so promptly.  I’m no Excel whiz, I just know how to find answers to questions online.   

First, I want to round up, not down.

Here’s how I want the rounding up to occur:
Minutes:

    1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=7, 8=15, 9=15, 10=15, 11=15, 12=15, 13=15, 14=15, 15=15, 16=16, 17=17, 18=18,  ETC

Again, I’d like minutes to be rounded up as follows (the 4 thresholds are 8, 23, 38 & 53)

     8 minutes or above: round up to 15 
     / 23 minutes or above: round up to 30 
     / 38 minutes or above: round up to 45 
     / 53 minutes or above: round up to 60

~ Jay

Comment: Here's another way to put it (pardon me, I don't know syntax):  =IF(A1(1-7,1-7(8-15,15(16-22,16-22(23-30,30(31-37,31-37(38-45,45(46-52,46-52(53-60,60)

Answer (score 0):

How's this go?

```
DECLARE @time DATETIME = '2014-03-19T09:59:00'

SELECT CASE 
          WHEN DATEPART(mi, @time) BETWEEN 8 AND 15 THEN DATEADD(mi, 15-DATEPART(mi, @time), @time) 
          WHEN DATEPART(mi, @time) BETWEEN 23 AND 30 THEN DATEADD(mi, 30-DATEPART(mi, @time), @time)
          WHEN DATEPART(mi, @time) BETWEEN 38 AND 45 THEN DATEADD(mi, 45-DATEPART(mi, @time), @time)
          WHEN DATEPART(mi, @time) BETWEEN 53 AND 59 THEN DATEADD(mi, 60-DATEPART(mi, @time), @time)
          ELSE @time
       END
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I'm 60 years old and VERY new to Excel.  Would you please be willing to spell this out for me a bit more?  How would I write this as a formula???

Comment: Hi Jay. You've posted this in the SQL Server part of this forum, and I've answered it as if the question was about SQL Server, not Excel. None of your tags indicate this is an Excel issue, nor the opening question. I'd suggest that you update the question and tags so that others don't come to this conclusion. So far two of us have thought this was a SQL Server issue. –  Stuart